# Incompatible data types in Java, array and integer

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I'm trying to get a program so that it loops and adds up the sum of an array. My code appears to be working, with the exception that it states that the text[j] in `adding = adding + text[j]` is an incompatible type (I'm assuming data type). Earlier in the code, I have `int adding = 0;`. This is the erroneous code:

```
for (int j=0;j<=total;j++){
       adding = adding + text[j];
       System.out.println(text[j]);
    }
```

where total is the limiting factor. If I put:

```
for (int j=0;j<= total;j++){
       adding = adding + j;
       System.out.println(text[j]);
    }
```

the program compiles but gives 45, which is incorrect.

Why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: What's `text` defined as? `char[]`? `String`?

Comment: text is a string. could that be the problem?

Comment: @ChaseYuan Of course. In Java, strings aren't arrays of numeric types, but an opaque (-ish) data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer actually turned out to be outside the code given. I had set my array to be a `String`, not an `int` as it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

If your `text[]` is `String[]` or `char[]` as the name suggests then I believe you are trying to update `text[]` elements with suffix `j` or `adding`, which you can write as:

If it is `char[]` then write

```
    text[j] = (char)(adding + (int)text[j]);
```

If it is `String[]` then write

```
     text[j]= text[j]+adding;
```

as required. It all depends on what is the data type of `text[]` and what are you trying to achieve?

Also as suggested in one of the answers, if `total` is length of the array, then change the comparison to `<` to avoind `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Your second example, adds `j` into `adding` but prints `text[j]` value, which is nothing to do with the addition of `adding` and `j`.